# Postgresql frequency table with percentage partition over and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, frequency

I'm trying to create a frequency table with percentage in Postgresql

If anyone is familiar with SAS i'm trying to recreate a proc frequency table

Below I'm trying to get the frequency with a group by on var1,var2

```
var1     var2    frequency  percentage 
A        20       1          33%
A        30       1          33%
A        40       1          33%
B        20       4          80%
B        30       1          20%
```

Now that is easy with just

```
select var1
,var2
,count(*)
from table
group by 1,2
```

What gets tricky is where I try to add a percentage column which does % based on var1 distribution

```
select var1
,var2
,count(*)
,count(*)/count(*) over(partition by var1)
from table
group by 1,2
```

I get a wrong answer with the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to *sum* the `count(*)` values.  So:

```
select var1, var2, count(*),
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over (partition by var1)
from table
group by 1, 2;
```

Your code just counts the number of rows for each `var` *after* the aggregation.  Hence, it is actually returning the weighted average -- something that might be useful but not what you want.

Comment: It worked fine thanks! I'm not too sure why summing the count(*) over the partition gives you the pre aggregation sum?

Comment: @Mobix . . . I tried to explain that in the answer.  The `count(*)` is the result of the aggregation on each row of the result set.  The `sum()` then adds this up over all rows -- the total count.